Large size of CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu
I am using Ubuntu in WSL. On my disk C, CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_79rhkp1fndgsc is occupying 250 GB on my computer.

I think this is a lot, since on Ubuntu I do not have more than 20 GB  of files.

How much disk space does Ubuntu normally need in WSL?

How can I check what is stored there?



This question is similar to: Understanding disk space using WSL2. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have found this post Understanding disk space using WSL2
According to what I understand 250 GB is the allocated space to Ubuntu, not the filled space.
In Windows, this space is shown as filled 250/250 GB, but in truth, when checking in the virtual machine, that space is not occupied. it is only 15/250 GB.
To check the occupied size, I have used in windows powershell the command:
 wsl df -h /


As the author of the post you referenced in your self-answer, I'm sorry to say that your understanding of it is incorrect.  I apologize that my answer there was apparently not clear enough.  It's certainly a confusing topic, so let me try to clarify here for your particular case. It's going to be best if you do some more experimentation on your own to make sure you understand fully, though.

Being "sparse" means that the size of the drive to Ubuntu can be larger than the actual size of the ext4.vhdx file.

BUT, the converse is not true.  If your ext4.vhdx file is showing 250GB in Windows, then that is (probably) the amount of space it is actually taking from Windows.
I say "probably", because it looks like you are using TreeSize to get the filesize.  It's almost certainly reporting the actual size of the file. Note the "percent of parent" numbers there. But according to this TreeSize doc, TreeSize does treat sparse and compressed files somewhat differently, so you might try turning on the "Compression" column to see what it shows.
Or view the same file in Windows Explorer - It will show the actual size for certain.

wsl df -h / is showing the state of the drive to Ubuntu. But that number is mostly unrelated to the size that it takes up on Windows. It just doesn't give you enough information here to help.


So, on your system:

250GB is the maximum sparse size of the virtual disk. This means that the virtual drive itself to Ubuntu has 250GB capacity.  It also means that the actual size-on-disk to Windows can be anywhere between (nearly) 0 bytes and 250GB depending on whether it has grown or not.

250GB also appears to be the amount of space that the ext4.vhdx file is taking up on the Windows drive. Usually, when the (1) and (2) numbers match, it's because the contents of your Ubuntu virtual drive grew to 250GB at some point.
As noted in my linked answer, the sparse file can grow, but it doesn't shrink back down when files in it are deleted. To do that, you have to either enable a new option or manually shrink it as mentioned in the answer that that answer links to - How do I get back unused disk space from Ubuntu on WSL2?.

The size of the current contents of your virtual drive is 15GB, which means that after shrinking, you will hopefully find that:

The size of the ext4.vhdx shrinks to 15GB.
Windows now has another 235GB available.




thanks NotTheDr01ds  =) now is clear for me!
